# ResultSet.next() is getting stuck on last result

Tags: java, oracle

I am executing a a join sql query that should return 1000 rows, when it reaches last row, it hangs on next(). (the expected return value should be false)

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rSet;
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

rSet = ps.executeQuery();
while (rSet.next()) { //Hangs on count 999

}
```

Can't understand what could be a reason.

Not sure if it's relevant but the select has a where in clause with 1000 numbers.

Comment: Perhaps there is an issue with the connection and connection timeout is set to infinite? Try setting fetchSize for the query to 1000

Comment: please provide more information, like how you connect to db, using connection pool? datasource? please more code.....

Comment: Ok, it hangs on count 999 but, let's say you print something in the loop.. then count the lines... is it 1000? or 999? I suspect it may have something to do with the logic of counting iterations and the use of next()